# NASM and a clarification on POP

Tags: assembly, nasm, 32-bit

I've been learning me some Assembly lately and am writing really simple programs just to see how things work and to remember things better.

Anyway, I decided to simply write a program that prints your input. I'm using SASM and its io macros.

```
%include "io.inc"

section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
segment .data
    message db "Input a number", 0 
segment .bss
    input resb 4
    input2 resb 4
segment .text

    PRINT_STRING message ;prints message
    GET_UDEC 4, eax ;gets 4bytes of user input and puts into eax
    mov [input], eax ;moves eax into input's actual data
    PRINT_UDEC 4, input ;prints input
    NEWLINE
    PRINT_UDEC 4, esp ;Prints 2686764
    NEWLINE
    push input ;pushes input onto the stack
    PRINT_UDEC 4, esp ;Prints 2686760, we pushed a dw
    NEWLINE

    pop ebx ;pops (input) and puts it into ebx?
    mov [input2], ebx ;moves ebx into input2
    PRINT_UDEC 4, input2 ;prints input2. //Prints some crazy number.

    GET_UDEC 4, eax ;Stops program from exiting.

xor eax, eax
ret
```

I must be missing something elementary here, but I can't find it to save my life. Anyone know?

Comment: You probably want `push [input]` otherwise you might be pushing the address not the value.

Comment: The god forsaken brackets strike again! 'push dword [input]' works.

Comment: **The god forsaken brackets strike again!** I thank God every day for those brackets! Assemblers that don't use them keep confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem With Your Code**

Before I answer your question about pop I would like to say that you should do `push dword [input]` instead of `push input` so that you push the value of input instead of a pointer to it.

**pop and push Explanation**

In assembly there are four main ways to interact with the stack. `push` pushes the first argument to the top of the stack. `pop` takes the **top element** from the stack and puts it into the first argument. `pusha` pushes all the registers to the stack. `popa` is like pusha but pops all the registers instead.

You can also change the location of the stack by changing the `esp` register. And example of this is:

```
mov esp, 0x100000
mov ebp, esp
```

This will set the stack to be at memory location 0x100000. Please note that this is rarely done by programs and only by the OS or system.

Comment: `pusha` and `popa` are available as o16 or o32, and either can be used in 16-bit and 32-bit CS by use of prefixes. The instructions can be called `pushaw` and `pushad` to make the size explicit. In 64-bit CS however the instructions are invalid.

Comment: Hi, I am speaking from experience as for in a os kernel or Linux program I get an error when ever I try to use pusha or popa

Comment: What does "an error" mean? There shouldn't be any problem running this except for Long mode 64-bit CS. Just tested running `pushaw` and `pushad` in a 16-bit native DPMI CS and a 32-bit native DPMI CS, both on an AMD64 server. They work just fine.

Comment: Ohhh. The error is coming from LD not nasm. I’ll update the post.

Comment: `push [input]` has to be `push dword [input]`.  NASM only assumed a default size = bitness of the mode for push-immediate, not for push-memory.